# openCV: Trying to understand capture video from camera code

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv

Below is the simple code from openCV document to open and close webcam,

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

while(True):
    # Capture frame-by-frame
    ret, frame = cap.read()

    # Our operations on the frame come here
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

    # Display the resulting frame
    cv2.imshow('frame',gray)
    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break

# When everything done, release the capture
cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

**Questions:**

1) What is the use numpy library in above code and why it is required?

2) How to see the return value of `cv2.waitKey(0)`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. No use here. Nevertheless it is a module that finds its way into many code snippets due to its many uses (many of them go hand in hand with `cv2`).
2. `Python: cv.WaitKey(delay=0) → int` [Doc](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/highgui/doc/user_interface.html?highlight=waitkey)... Just use regular assignment from the function
3. `cap.release()` [See example here](https://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/doc/py_tutorials/py_gui/py_video_display/py_video_display.html)

Comment: Thanks for your response. My 3rd question didn't get resolved. Using `cap.release()` webcam is not getting switched OFF. How to turn it OFF?

Comment: From the codumentation it seems that `.release()` shuold suffice. Try `cap.__del__()` and report back

Comment: Getting attribute error. `AttributeError: 'cv2.VideoCapture' object has no attribute '__del__'`

Comment: You can also try `del(cap)` but even if this would work, it isn't a by-the-book solution, AFAIK

Comment: Additionally, what is the value of `cap.isOpened()` when you see the light is still on?

Comment: `del(cap)` - doesn't work. Value of `cap.isOpened() --> False`

Comment: If `cap.isOpened() --> False` then there is nothing else to do, I believe. Guessing the light controller is bugged, or the destructor is...

Comment: I think, we need to check in source code of `cv2.VideoCapture()`, which is beyond my scope. Anyways thanks :)